# Error sending message to specific channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot on Discord.py and I'm trying to set the channel I want to send a message to using an argument.
The code is this:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, arg1):
    channel = client.get_channel(arg1)
    await channel.send('Message')
```

When I type the channel id instead of arg1, it works, but when I type the command on Discord (!send 282772187812) it doesn't work and I get this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a `try : except:` to send a message on error and attempt to resume execution

Comment: No, I haven't tried that

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html shows the channel id should be an int, but I believe arg1 is a string here. Don't know if it matters but you may want to try casting arg1 to an int.

Answer (score 0):

As @backcab said, you can either convert `arg1` to an integer or use channel converters from [ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters).

**Solution 1**

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, arg1):
    channel = client.get_channel(int(arg1))
    await channel.send('Message')
```

**Solution 2**

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):        
    await channel.send('Message')
```